# How to Bypass Puppeteer Blocking Systems

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, puppeteer

I would like to open https://krunker.io/ through Puppeteer. However, whenever I open up Krunker.io through Puppeteer, it blocks me, saying "Puppeteer Detected". Is there an easy workaround to this?
One answer I got was this:

> You need to make a matchmaker seek game request to get a websocket URL, and then you connect to it and simulate being a client

As I started coding Node.js and in Javascript just under 5 weeks ago, I am not sure how to do this. (I asked, and he said "just do it". It's probably not that hard, I am just not that good at Node). Here is all of the answers I came across:

> i just made my rce code in assembly and then link it with chrome executable and then using a hex dumper replace the rce function call bytes with a reference pointer to my own code. 
> also you need to make sure your rce code has the correct signature otherwise the rebuilt chrome executable will crash as soon as it reaches your rce runtime code

> you can also append a EYF_33 byte after the ACE_26 bytes to grant GET requests to make  it possible to create 2 PATCH requests at a time with different structures makiong it possible to create fully independent websocket connection to the krunker api and send more AES authorization messages at a time

Not sure what this means ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Is there a *simple* way to do this, or better yet, a step-by-step tutorial on how to do this (on a mac)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases it is detecting by user agent. Simplified you can use [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra) and the plugin [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) to change your user agent.

Comment: Are those plugins still a form of Puppeteer?

Comment: sure, puppeteer-extra is only a wrapper that allows to use "extra" plugins around native puppeteer